# HHVM connect mariadb fail

Tags: php, mysql, hhvm

HHVM can't connect to **mariadb** and **mysqldb**, but php can,I don't know why,someone please help me.

```
[root@localhost /]#hhvm --version

HipHop VM 3.2.0 (rel)
Compiler: 1407404220_188959187
Repo schema: 190259736_1407404220

[root@localhost /]#php /var/www/html/test.php

Tom
Jack

[root@localhost /]#hhvm /var/www/html/test.php

Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.135.142' (4) in /var/www/html/test.php on line 2
Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.135.142' (4)
```

the code in /var/www/html/test.php:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("192.168.135.142","admin","123");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytest");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Don't bother trying to make it work on HHVM, instead, sped that time refactoring your code to use one of `mysql_*`'s replacement extensions (either `mysqli_*` or `PDO`), both of which work on HHVM

Comment: thanks,@Elias Van Ootegem ,but when I run the code:
$link = new mysqli("192.168.135.142","admin","123","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));It doesn't work.Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.135.142' (4)

Comment: The error message you're getting suggests you're still using a `mysql_*` function. Besides, to see the connection error for the `mysqli` extension, you need `$link->connect_error` or `mysqli_connect_error()`: [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem ,I run the code:$link = new mysqli("192.168.135.142","admin","123","test") or die("Error " . mysqli_connect_error());It's the same error.I think hhvm support mysql or mysqli?Or I need to install something?I really don't know why my hhvm can't connect mariadb.

Comment: facebook said hhvm support mysql and pdo:https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Extensions ,I can connect mariadb via pdo,but can't connect via mysql,I am so confuse.

Comment: Have you installed hhvm with the required extensions? Are you sure the IP shown in the error msg is correct? Have you double-checked to see if there are no syntax errors? Have you tried pinging the db server? Have you tried connecting to it via command-line or some other tool, to make sure you're using the correct credentials? There are so many things that could be wrong here, it's impossible to formulate a definitive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have connectted to mariadb successfully.Just find my.cnf,and add:skip-name-resolve below[mysqld],and mysql_connect work.